# Grails and MongoDb (persistent instance deletion)

Tags: mongodb, grails

If I have a Grails application which I have used to persist some domain objects to my database (MongoDb in this case but probably does not matter), and I modify my domain class, say I add some more properties or take some properties away. Now, will the modified version of the application with the newer version of the domain class still recognize the already persisted old version of the domain instances?

**More importantly if I now restart the Grails application with the new version of the domain class, will it delete(or do anything to) the already persisted old versions of the domain objects?** I am trying to chase a similar issue I am facing but I am on a team so I'm not sure if the application deleted the old objects from the db (which I don't think so) or did some human system user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way in which Grails handles the database depends on the value of the dbCreate property  in DataSource.groovy.

If you declare

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update"
}
```

then any additional properties you add to your domain class will be added as columns in your database. Note that this will not delete any columns that already exist. So say you had a property called x and wanted to replace it with a property called y, this would create a y column in the database but the x column would still remain.

Here a list of the possible values and behaviors for dbCreate

- **create** - Drops the existing schema. Creates the schema on startup, dropping existing tables, indexes, etc. first.
- **create-drop** - Same as create, but also drops the tables when the application shuts down cleanly.
- **update** - Creates missing tables and indexes, and updates the current schema without dropping any tables or data. Note that this can't properly handle many schema changes like column renames (you're left with the old column containing the existing data).
- **validate** - Makes no changes to your database. Compares the configuration with the existing database schema and reports warnings.
- **any other value** - does nothing

Hope this helps

Comment: Given that I defined no such propert, it isn't possible that the application could have deleted the missing data then right?

Comment: @AnonymousHuman This would depend on what type of environment your application is running in. By default, DataSource.groovy has the following values for dbCreate in the development, test, and production environments -
development: create-drop,
test: update,
production: update.
So if you were running your application from the command line with 'run-app' you would be in the development environment by default. If you were running it from a war file on a server then you would be in the production environment by default. How are you running your application?

Comment: I am running my application in two different places. One in dev and other in prod. But your explanation is what I needed to understand how the two environment work as far as datasource interaction. Now, I think I have a better understanding. Thanks.